# Concurrent Spring Boot tests using JUnit 5 are starting mulitple JVMs

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, junit5

I'm using the [new JUnit 5 concurrency feature](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution) to run multiples `@SpringBootTest` classes in parallel. It works great with a small test set but once I run all the tests classes, it's going to start **multiple** instances of my Spring Boot app. It's pretty easy to see in the logs (I'm using [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/)).

I'm pretty sure this isn't supposed to happen since I didn't find anything about this behavior in the JUnit/Spring Boot docs.

What is even weirder is that it seems to spawn new instances randomly. It starts with 2 at the beginning and new ones are getting spun up during the execution (which pauses while the server starts). However, it's always the **same** process ID as if instances were destroyed and recreated along the way... (see logs below)

Here's my config:

- spring-boot:  2.3.8.RELEASE
- junit-platform: 1.7.1
- junit-jupiter: 5.7.1
- Running tests on Windows 10 and IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.4 (Community Edition) but same behavior happens with `mvn test`

`junit-platform.properties` configuration:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default=concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default=concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
```

All tests classes are annotated with the following:

```java
@Import({ PostgresqlTestConfig.class, MailTestConfig.class, ServerContext.class, CaptchaTestConfig.class })
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyApp.class }, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("prod")
```

In the logs, I can clearly see the SB app starting procedure multiples times:

```
        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.3.8.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2021-03-30 23:47:08.593  INFO 7200 --- [Pool-1-worker-5] .w.w.w.r.a.JwtAuthenticationResourceTest : Starting JwtAuthenticationResourceTest on MSI with PID 7200 
...
... (initializing the context here, i.e embedded PostgreSQL, running Liquibase, etc...)
...
2021-03-30 23:48:54.811  INFO 7200 --- [Pool-1-worker-5] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_MSI1617140910513 started.
2021-03-30 23:48:54.850  INFO 7200 --- [Pool-1-worker-5] .w.w.w.r.a.JwtAuthenticationResourceTest : Started JwtAuthenticationResourceTest in 106.911 seconds (JVM running for 118.405)

... Then a bit later ...


        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝

:: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 2.3.8.RELEASE ::
:: http://jhipster.github.io ::

2021-03-30 23:51:14.626  INFO 7200 --- [Pool-1-worker-3] c.w.w.security.AuthenticationFlowTest    : Starting AuthenticationFlowTest on MSI with PID 7200
...
...
```

I hope somebody encountered the same problem. I doubt it's a configuration issue since pretty much everything is out of the box here...

Thanks in advance for everyone's time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long and tedious process of trial and errors, I figured it out and it's pretty simple.

It's in no way related to JUnit 5 or the parallel execution and it was already happening before I use it on the project. It's related to **Spring Boot tests not reusing application context** in some cases.

Further details there:

- [Spring boot test: context loaded for every test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929585/spring-boot-test-context-loaded-for-every-test)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7174

Once all my test classes are using the exact same context configuration, only one server/context is loaded and parallel execution is working well !